# Monotonicity of tangent

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

obviously for $a,b \in ]\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$ the ordinary tangent map is strictly monotonic. Hence for $b \geq a \Rightarrow \tan(b) \geq \tan(a)$. In the proof I try to understand it follows that $\tan(]a,b[)=]\tan(a),\tan(b)[$. I need this since once proven I can conclude that tan maps open sets to open sets. It is clear that this statement is indeed true, but how to prove?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, for any continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you have $f([a,b]) = [\min{f},\max{f}]$ and in particular if $f$ is monotonic you know what the max and min are

Comment: It is a consequence of th *intermediate value theorem*.

Comment: @user25959 Thanks, your first statement follows from the fact that any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact and since f is continous it follows that the image contains the minimum and maximum?

Comment: The fact that the image is an interval follows from intermediate value theorem. That fact about maximum and minimum being attained is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\in (a,b)\Longleftrightarrow a<x<b$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow a<x\ and\ x<b$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow tan(a)<tan(x)\ and\ tan(x)<tan(b)$$
which follows due to monotonicity of tangent function
$$\Longleftrightarrow tan(x)\in(tan(a),tan(b))$$

Hope it is helpful